# Scroll Viewer does not work

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, scrollviewer

I am creating A WPF window. This window contains a user control which in turn contains an item control. This user control can be of any height, hence i wanted to put a scroll bar. I am using the below code, but it doesn't works. Can some one point what change should i make

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
    <UC:History x:Name="ucHistory"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Update :
Thanks J.H. U set the height to the scroll viewer and that worked
My ques is , how would i know the height at run time as the alllication can run on any system display size, 
basicly i want to put scroll over ucPatientHistory control below
**Outer User control (this is added to window)**

```
                <!-- right bottom-->
                <UC:PatientDispensationHistory x:Name="ucPatientHistory"/>

            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>

        <!-- Left Side-->
        <UC:NewDispensation x:Name="ucDispenceAgain"/>

    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

**UC:PatientDispensationHistory**

```
<ScrollViewer Height="250">
    <GroupBox Header="Visit History" >
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="No Visit History"  Visibility="{Binding NoVisitText}" x:Name="txtNoVisit"/>

        <ItemsControl Name="CtrlPatientVisitHistory" Margin="8" ItemsSource="{Binding PatientVisitDetails}">
.....
       </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
    </GroupBox >
</ScrollViewer >
```

Comment: Try setting the scrollviewer's height, it might be growing with the user control.

Comment: HI J.H., how shall i do that? I have couple of other controls on the screen and screen size would vary from system to system.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing more of your xaml.  Maybe this link will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132967/scrollviewer-not-scrolling-in-wpf

Comment: Please post some more xaml code.